# How to check if $row['column_name'] is returning empty php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns

```
id,name,phone,describe
```

While fetching the values from this table i am using

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query)
```

Now i want to check whether

```
$row['describe']
```

is returning empty value. How to check in php??

Comment: You might want to consider moving away from the mysql functions. They are [deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). Just a heads up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `==0`, this will check if it equals to 0:

```
if ($row['describe']==0) { /* code to do */ }
```

Or `empty()`, this will check if it is empty:

```
if (empty($row['describe'])) { /* code to do */ }
```

Personally, I would prefer `!empty()` as this will check if the variable is empty.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
if(empty($row['describe'])) {
    //$row['describe'] is empty
} else {
    //$row['describe'] is not empty
}
```

Also please dont use `mysql_*`. It's deprecated and removed from PHP 7. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: yes. While adding data if i am leaving that field empty its not working. And for my requirement i am using checkbox to store data and imploding multiple checkbox values. And while exploding i want to check whether the field is empty.

Comment: Your question is different from this comment.

Answer (score 3):

This can help you. First check the query doesn't return empty then check the `describe` column is not empty. Only then go for performing action(s).

```
if ((mysql_num_rows($result) !=0 ) && (!empty($row['describe']) ) 
{ //PERFORM ACTION }
```

Comment: your answer needs correction, author doesn't want to check if row is empty but the column is empty...

Answer (score 3):

Use if condition like below

```
if ($row['describe'] == ""){
     echo "Description is empty";
}else{
    echo $row['describe'];
}
```

Comment: did you loop the content ?

Comment: No. Before looping i am checking whether its empty.